# Creating a lock-free memory pool using C++11 features

Tags: c++, c++11, lock-free

I have created a thread-safe and lock-free memory pool program using C++11 features. A couple of notable features:

- `g_memStack` is a stack that contains the memory unit; we can allocate memory from it.
- `g_waitingReclaims` is something like a stack that contains units waiting reclaim from the memory unit.
- `g_allocatingCounter` is a counter to specify the thread number in the `Allocate` function. It will have a value of 1 to indicate that there is no other thread waiting to allocate memory from the pool. This indicates that it is safe to reclaim memory in `g_waitingReclaims`.

I am looking for a review of both *correctness* and *style*. Specifically:

- Is there anything wrong with the memory ordering in `g_allocatingCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed` (the first line in the `Allocate` function?)?
- Is it possible that the next line (`MemUnit *unit = g_memStack.load(std::memory_order_acquire);` could be re-ordered to execute first at runtime?
- If so, how would I fix that? Could I just change the memory order to `std::memory_order_acquire`? Would that require another release operation to cooperate with it (I don't think so, because [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) said `std::memory_order_acquire` will prevent read and write from reordering before it)?
- Anything else?

````
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>

struct MemUnit
{
    MemUnit *m_next;//next unit
    void    *m_data;//memory for data
};

void                    *g_buffer{nullptr};
std::atomic<MemUnit *>  g_memStack{};
std::atomic<MemUnit *>  g_waitingReclaims{};
std::atomic<uint32_t>   g_allocatingCounter{};

void InitMemPool(size_t poolSize, size_t blockSize);
void UninitMemPool();

MemUnit *StepToTail(MemUnit* listHead);
void Reclaim(MemUnit* listHead, MemUnit* listTail);
void GiveBackToWaitings(MemUnit* listHead, MemUnit* listTail);

MemUnit *Allocate()
{
    g_allocatingCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);//Warning: Something wrong with the memory order. It maybe reorder after the next line at runtime.
    MemUnit *unit = g_memStack.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    while (unit != nullptr && !g_memStack.compare_exchange_weak(unit, unit->m_next, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_acquire));
    if (g_allocatingCounter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
    {
        MemUnit *pendingList = g_waitingReclaims.exchange(nullptr, std::memory_order_acquire);
        const bool canReclaim = g_allocatingCounter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1;//this operation can not reorder before exchange operation Just because the 'memory_order_acquire'
        //If 'canReclaim' is true, it's ABA problem free. Because there is nobody in 'Allocate' hold same pointer within pending list.
        if (canReclaim && pendingList != nullptr)
        {
            canReclaim ? Reclaim(pendingList, StepToTail(pendingList)) : GiveBackToWaitings(pendingList, StepToTail(pendingList));
        }
        return unit;
    }
    g_allocatingCounter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);//this operation can not reorder before 'compare_exchange_weak' Just because the 'memory_order_acquire'
    return unit;
}

void FreeMemUnit(MemUnit* item)
{
    item->m_next = g_waitingReclaims.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (!g_waitingReclaims.compare_exchange_weak(item->m_next, item, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}

MemUnit *StepToTail(MemUnit* listHead)
{
    assert(listHead != nullptr);
    while (listHead->m_next) listHead = listHead->m_next;
    return listHead;
}

void Reclaim(MemUnit* listHead, MemUnit* listTail)
{
    listTail->m_next = g_memStack.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (!g_memStack.compare_exchange_weak(listTail->m_next, listHead, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}

void GiveBackToWaitings(MemUnit* listHead, MemUnit* listTail)
{
    listTail->m_next = g_waitingReclaims.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (!g_waitingReclaims.compare_exchange_weak(listTail->m_next, listHead, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    //Yes, it's 'relaxed' memory order when it's success.
}

void InitMemPool(size_t poolSize, size_t blockSize)
{
    const size_t unitSize = sizeof(MemUnit) + blockSize;
    g_buffer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(std::malloc(unitSize * poolSize));

    MemUnit* next = nullptr;
    uint8_t* rawBuffer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(g_buffer);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != poolSize; ++i)
    {
        MemUnit* pObj = reinterpret_cast<MemUnit *>(rawBuffer);
        pObj->m_next = next;
        next = pObj;
        rawBuffer += unitSize;
    }
    g_memStack.store(next, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void UninitMemPool()
{
    assert(g_allocatingCounter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0);

    g_memStack.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    g_waitingReclaims.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::free(g_buffer);
    g_buffer = nullptr;
}



void WorkThread()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 128; ++i)
    {
        MemUnit *unit = Allocate();
        if (unit != nullptr)
        {
            //do something use unit.m_data;
            FreeMemUnit(unit);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    InitMemPool(128, 1024);

    std::vector<std::thread> allThreads;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 8; ++i)
    {
        std::thread t(WorkThread);
        allThreads.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    for (auto &t : allThreads)
    {
        t.join();
    }
    UninitMemPool();
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Please check your [initialization of the atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453054/initialize-static-atomic-member-variable) to be correct. I don't know if it is, but there is usually some very weird stuff going on if done wrong.

Comment: @ThomasLang: the 3 `atomic<T>` variables are all pointer-sized or 32-bit, and have static storage duration.  On normal C++ implementations (like x86 gcc or MSVC, or ARM, or whatever), they will be lock-free, and thus zero-initialization of their object representation will give correct behaviour.  (As far as C++ language rules, yes, it's a good idea to make sure you init them correctly, but this doesn't explain any weirdness observed on real systems.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I have completed the code.  Yes, i didn't observe anything weird. The program is just a practice and i can't guarantee it works as what i think(Some times it's really hard to find bugs behind lock-free codes).  So i came here and wanted to known what others thinking about this(Yes, it's really like a code review).

Comment: @Cody: nice edit!  Typo: `aquery`  -> `acquire` (I don't have 2k rep on this .SE to fix it myself.)

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: I think there is something wrong in Allocate. That is a store operation about 'fetch_add' , and the store maybe reorder after the next load. The right way is change both of the fetch_add and next load to be memory_order_seq_cst operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'g_memStack' is a stack that contains memory unit. We can allocate
>   memory unit from it

There is not a single line of code allocating `MemUnit`

> This a thread safe and lock-free memory pool program

Unfortunately this is not true. Assume two threads are executing `Allocate` on an empty stack in a fully interleaved manner.

```
g_allocatingCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); //T1 : 1, T2 : 2
MemUnit *unit = g_memStack.load(std::memory_order_acquire);  //T1 : nullptr, T2 : nullptr
while (unit != nullptr && !g_memStack.compare_exchange_weak(unit, unit->m_next, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_acquire));
if (g_allocatingCounter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
{
   //let's assume its fine here
    return unit; // T1 : something
}
g_allocatingCounter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
return unit; //T2 : nullptr
```

They reach `if (g_allocatingCounter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)` with the variable `unit` being null. The condition is true for one thread but not the other.

The thread for which the condition is false will return `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the function is allowed to return nullptr.

Comment: For future readers: this was posted as an answer to the original question, before migration from Stack Overflow.  That's why it doesn't look like a code review.

Answer (score 2):

## Includes and types

> ```
> std::atomic<uint32_t>
> ```

You need to include `<stdint.h>` for this type.  Or better, include `<cstdint>` and use `std::uint32_t` instead; same for `std::uint8_t`.  Similarly:

> ```
> const size_t unitSize = sizeof(MemUnit) + blockSize;
> ```

Spell that `std::size_t`.  Although implementations are *permitted* to add global-namespace versions of these identifiers, they are not *required* to, so relying on that is a portability issue waiting to bite.

---

## Interface

It's not clear whether all the functions are intended to be part of the public interface.  Certainly there are several which aren't directly needed by the test program, so perhaps they could be moved into an anonymous namespace?

The naming of the functions is somewhat unconventional - it may well be worth re-reading the `std::allocator` interface to see what's expected.

`InitMemPool` and `UninitMemPool` look very much like they should be an allocator's constructor and destructor, respectively.  As free functions, they are vulnerable to misuse (e.g. calling either of them more than once, or using `Allocate()` before init or after uninit).

---

## Use of `std::atomic`

I haven't fully audited the memory barriers here, and it's less my area of expertise, so I'm hoping another reviewer will give that some scrutiny.